Remove certain characters in a string
I have this is text or markdown format file in windows 10.
i want to use replace all command to replace t=25s, t=95s, t=180s with t=25, t=95, t-180. I need to get rid of s
What  command can i do in  regex find/replace to achieve the above. Thanks
I have access to  regex find/replace plugin or search & replace in obsidian. I  cant figure out the command.

This?: https://help.obsidian.md/Plugins/Search It doesn't say anything about replacing but you can search with the content: operator https://help.obsidian.md/Plugins/Search#Search+operators

You will get better attention if you edit your question tags to be "obsidian" and "regex". String and character are really vague.

I updated the tags. Thanks. In regex there is a command to do this.  I cant figure that out. I am not a techie. For now  i found a way to do it using Notepad++
Open the file in notepad ++
Press Ctrl+H to open the Replace dialog.

In the "Find what" box, enter (t=\d+)s.
In the "Replace with" box, enter \1.

But i need the solution in regex

After a Google search, I found this feature request about the regex find&replace:
https://forum.obsidian.md/t/implement-regex-search-and-replace-within-files/65712/3
They suggest using a plugin to provide the feature: https://github.com/Gru80/obsidian-regex-replace

Like @hNczy mentioned, you can use the Regex community plugin for jobs like this. Install it, press Ctrl + P and search for regex to open the plugin. You can give it a hotkey if you want.
The expression in your comment works perfectly:

Just replace with $1 instead of \1. The command above deletes the blue sections below:


Thanks for all the answers. That solved my issue.

You're welcome dude. If you want to close your question, click the checkmark next to an answer to accept it :)
